# How can I change string into ASCII and then binary in C?

Tags: c

So I'm working on a problem asking me to change an user input string to ASCII then binary in recursive way. I managed to do this for a single character, but when I try to use a for loop it throw me a weird result. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char toBS;
    printf("Enter the string you want to convert: \n"); 
    scanf("%c", &toBS);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<toBS+1; i++){
        print(toBS);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    return;
}

void print(char c)
{
    int n = CHAR_BIT;
    binaryPrinter((unsigned char)c, &n);
    putchar('\n');
}

void binaryPrinter(int value, int *numberOfOnes)
{
    if((*numberOfOnes)--){
        binaryPrinter(value >> 1, numberOfOnes);
        printf("%d", value & 1);
    }
}
```

Here's my result:

Input: `a`

Output:

```
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
01100001
```

Comment: Why is this function recursive? Why not use `sizeof(unsigned char)*8` instead of `CHAR_BIT`? Why is `numberOfOnes` a pointer? I have way more questions than answers.

Comment: Tip: This would be utterly *trivial* to do with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Either your indentation is broken, or your coding style is very unclear. Regardless, `%c` is not getting you a string.

Comment: in your for loop you're comparing an int to a char, the comparison to toBS in the loop reads as 97 for input "a". print(toBS) is running 98 times, which is the number of times it shows in your posted output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from lousy formatting, there are a few problems with your code:

```
scanf("%c", &toBS);
// will only get one character, not a string.
// and there is no testing to see if scanf() actually worked.
```

```
for (i = 0; i < toBS + 1; i++) { // counts up to the ASCII character's value.
    print(toBS);
}
```

```
void print(char c) { // sole purpose is to add one parameter to recursive function call
```

```
printf("%d", value & 1); // all the machinery of 'printf()' to output either '0' or '1'
```

It can be made much simpler if you think your way through what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void asBin( char c, int b ) {
    if( b ) {
        asBin( c, b-1 );
        putchar( '0' + (1&(c>>(CHAR_BIT-b))) );
        if( b == CHAR_BIT ) putchar( ' ' );
    }
}

int main() {
    for( char *str = "Hello!"; *str; str++ )
        asBin( *str, CHAR_BIT );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100001
```

And even simpler if you apply the right method (iteration) instead of recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    for( char *str = "Hello!"; *str; str++ ) {
        for( int i = CHAR_BIT; i--;  )
            putchar( '0' + (1&(*str>>i)) );
        putchar( "\n "[str[1] != 0] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once the basics are in place, it's possible to rearrange things. The following (recursive) code outputs 3/4 of the 7-bit ASCII table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void asBin( uint8_t c, int b ) {
    if( --b ) asBin( (uint8_t)(c>>1), b );
    putchar( "01"[c&1] );
}

int main() {
    for( uint8_t cr = ' '; cr < ' '+32; cr++  ) {
        for( uint8_t cc = cr; cc < ' '+32+32+31; cc += 32 ) {
            printf( " %c ", cc );
            asBin( cc, 8 );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
   00100000 @ 01000000 ` 01100000
 ! 00100001 A 01000001 a 01100001
 " 00100010 B 01000010 b 01100010
 # 00100011 C 01000011 c 01100011
 $ 00100100 D 01000100 d 01100100
        /* omitted */
 9 00111001 Y 01011001 y 01111001
 : 00111010 Z 01011010 z 01111010
 ; 00111011 [ 01011011 { 01111011
 < 00111100 \ 01011100 | 01111100
 = 00111101 ] 01011101 } 01111101
 > 00111110 ^ 01011110 ~ 01111110
 ? 00111111 _ 01011111
```